# how to deploy the project in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, web-applications, web-deployment-project

Have create the project in asp.net web application ,then add the dbml file and Create new folder name is (urlImages) for upload. its working in local visual studio ,

how to deploy the project?

thanking you

Comment: Upload the files to a webserver.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the web project and Publish it. Than upload the published files to webserver.

Comment: but i have upload the image to folder ,publish file not contain image folder ,how to get it

Comment: For this you have 2 way outs, one is to make the image files as part of you project and they will be published as well or if you don't make them part of project, than simply create upload images to webserver in specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click the project, click on Publish and follow the instruction in the dialog box. There are several other options

- [Web Application Project Deployment Overview for Visual Studio and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx)
- [VS 2010 Web Deployment - ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)